# Drop Duplicates based on two different conditions

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset in this form:

```
Website    Revenue    Company_Age  Facebook    Twitter    CEO
xyz.com     345         45          0           0         NaN
abc.com     634         42          0           0         NaN
xyz.xom     345         55          1           0         NaN
def.com     732         63          1           0         NaN
rte.com     298         29          0           1         NaN
abc.com     553         20          0           1         NaN
```

So, I have to remove the duplicates from "Website" column..... But it should be done based on priority of Revenue and No. of Parameters.... For example, as you can see that abc.com is repeated 2 times...But the first one has higher Revenue than the second one. So, the second one will be deleted... Now, if you will see xyz.com, it's repeating and has same revenue values for both rows, so we have to move to no. of parameters ie. 'Facebook' and 'Twitter' column. So, Now, the first one xyz.com has total no. of parameters 0 where as second one has total no. of parameters 1, so first one xyz.com will be deleted...

Can someone pls help me out on how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by sorting the dataframe based on Revenue and Total_no_of_parameters column and then removing the duplicates by keeping the first element.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'websites' : ["xyz.com", "abc.com", "xyz.com", "def.com", "rte.com", "abc.com"],
'revenues' : [345, 634, 345, 732, 298, 553],
'company_ages' : [45, 42, 55, 63, 29, 20],
'facebooks' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
'twitters' : [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
'ceos' : [None, None, None, None, None, None]
})
```

create an extra column for sorting which can be deleted later

```
df['total_params'] = df['facebooks']+df['twitters']

df.sort_values(by=['revenues', 'total_params'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates('websites', keep='first', ignore_index=True)
```

**Result:**

```
websites    revenues    company_ages    facebooks   twitters    ceos    total_params
def.com     732     63      1       0       None        1
abc.com     634     42      0       0       None        0
xyz.com     345     55      1       0       None        1
rte.com     298     29      0       1       None        1
```